# Replace start menu list of recently used program with contents of a folder

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

Is it possible to replace the list of recently used programs with a list of all the files in my downloads folder? I hardly ever use that list as to access programs; I either have them pinned to my taskbar or I just search, and some on my desktop.

I download many files every day, so having a list of downloads in the start menu would be much more useful. I know modifying the start menu is possible as the application Start++ does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of directly, You can put the actual folder in the pinned items location so it expands, but for a folder in another location, you are limited to a shortcut. However, an alternative you may like is the following:

`Right click` on an empty part of the taskbar and go to `Toolbars > New toolbar`. Select the location of your `Download` folder and choose `Select Folder`.

[image]

You should now be able to access all items of the folder with just one click on the arrow.

Lastly, you can actually have the Downloads folder as an item on the right hand side of the Start Menu, For example -

[image]

You can do this by `right clicking` on the `Start Orb` and click `Properties`, next click `Customize` under the `Start Menu` tab and look for the `Downloads` section and change it to `Display as a menu`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have the downloads link but it displays in alphabetical order, when I need it to be ordered by date created.

Comment: I know you can manually re-arrange and also sort by name, but I do not know how to sort by date or anything else - sorry :(